# Are all derivatives either Lebesgue integrable or improper Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The function $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ is an example of a function whose derivative is not Lebesgue integrable on $[-1,1]$ but is improper Riemann integrable.

[Volterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) constructed a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ whose derivative is bounded (hence Lebesgue integrable) but not Riemann integrable (proper or improper).

> Is there a differentiable function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)$ is neither improper Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable on $[a,b]$?

Such a derivative is [Henstock–Kurzweil integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral)
, since *all* derivatives happen to be Henstock–Kurzweil integrable.

The example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75306/integrability-neither-improper-riemann-nor-lebesgue-but-henstock-kurzweil) unfortunately does not work. It has jump discontinuities, hence isn't a derivative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Combine your first example on one interval with your second on another.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thanks!